# C# al generar XML desde objeto hay campos que no son incluídos pero están ingresados

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework

Estoy generando un XML a partir de un objeto pero hay campos que no los está generando pero los mismos están siendo ingresados.

el objeto lo creo así:
Totales oTotales = new Totales();

Donde la clase totales ( que es obtenida a partir de un XSD ) es:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy")]
public partial class Totales {

    private TipMonType tpoMonedaField;

    private decimal tpoCambioField;

    private bool tpoCambioFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntNoGrvField;

    private bool mntNoGrvFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntExpoyAsimField;

    private bool mntExpoyAsimFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntImpuestoPercField;

    private bool mntImpuestoPercFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntIVaenSuspField;

    private bool mntIVaenSuspFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntNetoIvaTasaMinField;

    private bool mntNetoIvaTasaMinFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntNetoIVATasaBasicaField;

    private bool mntNetoIVATasaBasicaFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntNetoIVAOtraField;

    private bool mntNetoIVAOtraFieldSpecified;

    private decimal iVATasaMinField;

    private bool iVATasaMinFieldSpecified;

    private decimal iVATasaBasicaField;

    private bool iVATasaBasicaFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntIVATasaMinField;

    private bool mntIVATasaMinFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntIVATasaBasicaField;

    private bool mntIVATasaBasicaFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntIVAOtraField;

    private bool mntIVAOtraFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntTotalField;

    private decimal mntTotRetenidoField;

    private bool mntTotRetenidoFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntTotCredFiscField;

    private bool mntTotCredFiscFieldSpecified;

    private string cantLinDetField;

    private TotalesRetencPercep[] retencPercepField;

    private decimal montoNFField;

    private bool montoNFFieldSpecified;

    private decimal mntPagarField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public TipMonType TpoMoneda {
        get {
            return this.tpoMonedaField;
        }
        set {
            this.tpoMonedaField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal TpoCambio {
        get {
            return this.tpoCambioField;
        }
        set {
            this.tpoCambioField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool TpoCambioSpecified {
        get {
            return this.tpoCambioFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.tpoCambioFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntNoGrv {
        get {
            return this.mntNoGrvField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntNoGrvField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntNoGrvSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntNoGrvFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntNoGrvFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntExpoyAsim {
        get {
            return this.mntExpoyAsimField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntExpoyAsimField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntExpoyAsimSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntExpoyAsimFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntExpoyAsimFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntImpuestoPerc {
        get {
            return this.mntImpuestoPercField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntImpuestoPercField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntImpuestoPercSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntImpuestoPercFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntImpuestoPercFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntIVaenSusp {
        get {
            return this.mntIVaenSuspField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntIVaenSuspField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntIVaenSuspSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntIVaenSuspFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntIVaenSuspFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntNetoIvaTasaMin {
        get {
            return this.mntNetoIvaTasaMinField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntNetoIvaTasaMinField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntNetoIvaTasaMinSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntNetoIvaTasaMinFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntNetoIvaTasaMinFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntNetoIVATasaBasica {
        get {
            return this.mntNetoIVATasaBasicaField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntNetoIVATasaBasicaField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntNetoIVATasaBasicaSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntNetoIVATasaBasicaFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntNetoIVATasaBasicaFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntNetoIVAOtra {
        get {
            return this.mntNetoIVAOtraField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntNetoIVAOtraField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntNetoIVAOtraSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntNetoIVAOtraFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntNetoIVAOtraFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal IVATasaMin {
        get {
            return this.iVATasaMinField;
        }
        set {
            this.iVATasaMinField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool IVATasaMinSpecified {
        get {
            return this.iVATasaMinFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.iVATasaMinFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal IVATasaBasica {
        get {
            return this.iVATasaBasicaField;
        }
        set {
            this.iVATasaBasicaField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool IVATasaBasicaSpecified {
        get {
            return this.iVATasaBasicaFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.iVATasaBasicaFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntIVATasaMin {
        get {
            return this.mntIVATasaMinField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntIVATasaMinField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntIVATasaMinSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntIVATasaMinFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntIVATasaMinFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntIVATasaBasica {
        get {
            return this.mntIVATasaBasicaField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntIVATasaBasicaField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntIVATasaBasicaSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntIVATasaBasicaFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntIVATasaBasicaFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntIVAOtra {
        get {
            return this.mntIVAOtraField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntIVAOtraField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntIVAOtraSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntIVAOtraFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntIVAOtraFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntTotal {
        get {
            return this.mntTotalField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntTotalField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntTotRetenido {
        get {
            return this.mntTotRetenidoField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntTotRetenidoField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntTotRetenidoSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntTotRetenidoFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntTotRetenidoFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntTotCredFisc {
        get {
            return this.mntTotCredFiscField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntTotCredFiscField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MntTotCredFiscSpecified {
        get {
            return this.mntTotCredFiscFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.mntTotCredFiscFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")]
    public string CantLinDet {
        get {
            return this.cantLinDetField;
        }
        set {
            this.cantLinDetField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("RetencPercep")]
    public TotalesRetencPercep[] RetencPercep {
        get {
            return this.retencPercepField;
        }
        set {
            this.retencPercepField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MontoNF {
        get {
            return this.montoNFField;
        }
        set {
            this.montoNFField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MontoNFSpecified {
        get {
            return this.montoNFFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.montoNFFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal MntPagar {
        get {
            return this.mntPagarField;
        }
        set {
            this.mntPagarField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

lo estoy llenando así:

oTotales.MntIVATasaMin = 165.1;

oTotales.MntTotRetenido = 23;

y así son llenados todos los campos

el problema lo tengo cuando genero el xml ya que prticularmente he notado que los campos que tienen un dato ingresado pero FieldSpecified queda en false y no es agregado al xml, no entiendo porque queda en false cuando estoy asignando un valor.

Captura de algunos campos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cantidad, el mntTotal y otros más salen bien, los que están en false no salen, pero si debuggeo y cambio los valores a true, son generados.

Comment: pon un punto de control cuando vaya asignar los valores al objeto Totales, mirar los tipos que tienes por ejemplo si tienes doble y el objeto está como decimal...

Comment: Estoy pasando el mismo tipo de dato estoy casteando todo al pasarlo a (decimal)